# DDOS on port 443?

Tags: networking, router, denial-of-service

Recently my friend asked me whether his network is secure because he is setting up a game server on port XXX.

I opened up Nmap on my linux machine and found port 443 opened. I tried to access

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
```

It redirected me to his ISP's website. That means that his router responded to my web request.

How would hackers use this imformation to DDOS his router or gain unauthorised access to his network?

Comment: Please can you [edit] this question and add detail.  You found 443 open on what?  You tried to access what IP on port 443?  The internal host?  The router public address?  If public address of the router, how did you determine it?  If it goes to the ISP website, it is unlikely to have anything to do with his router.

Comment: [Port 443](https://www.grc.com/port_443.htm) is used for things like HTTPS and SSL/TLS. Should be fine.

Comment: Port 443 on his router's public address

Comment: Old question, but the public address you see first goes through the ISP (and then your ISP gateway to you) at which point the ISP could redirect it before you ever saw traffic on your side. I would determine this before worrying his actual router is doing the redirect. -IF- it is, the fix (I would recommend) would be to replace ISP consumer router w/ something like "OPNSense" or "DDWRT" or similar. If it's not, your ISP blocks use of 443 for themselves/their website - annoying, but nothing to really worry on. FIX: Change ISPs.

Answer (score 1):

If it redirected to the ISPs website than the ISP is likely not passing traffic on that port to your friend's router. As 443 is a common port used for hosting websites (HTTPS) it is typically blocked on most residential Internet connections.

If someone were to try and DDOS 443 they would likely end up DDOSing the ISP which wouldn't work out well for them.

I think your friend is probably safe from a DDOS on port 443.

Comment: You are assuming the given ISP is blocking floods / attacks. Some (definitely) do not, or do not have their firewalls/rate limiting/etc setup correctly to counter the newest flood or protocol attacks.